# Limit of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $Z_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables, which are uniformly picked from the interval $[1,2]$. Show that:
$$
\lim_{n_\rightarrow \infty}P\left(\left|\sqrt[n] {Z_1 Z_2\cdots Z_n}-\frac{4}{e}\right|>\epsilon\right)=0.
$$
I know I should probably apply the weak laws of large numbers, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Here you are trying to show that $\left(\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i\right)^{\frac1n}$ converges to $4e^{-1}$ in probability. Using @grand_chat's hint, you can turn this product into a sum so as to apply the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Can you please show how to turn the product into a sum? I'm having some trouble with that.

Comment: Recall that $\log(ab) = \log a+\log b$, $\log a^n = n\log a$, and $(ab)^{\frac1n} = a^{\frac 1n}b^{\frac 1n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply the weak law to the log of $\sqrt[n]{Z_1Z_2\cdots Z_n}$:

> $\ln\left[\left(Z_1Z_2\cdots Z_n\right)^{1/n}\right] =\frac1n \ln\left(Z_1Z_2\cdots Z_n\right) =\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\ln Z_i $.
> The resulting variables $\ln Z_1,\ln Z_2,\ldots,\ln Z_n$ are iid. To apply the LLN to them you need to calculate $E(\ln Z)=\int_1^2\ln z\,dz$.

Then use (or prove) the fact that if $X_n\to c$ in probability, with $c$ a constant, then $h(X_n)\to h(c)$ in probability whenever $h$ is continuous at $c$.

> For your problem you need a function that will undo the effect of the previous log transformation: $h(x)=\exp (x)$ is the right choice.

Comment: Could you give more details on that?